# Integrate startbootstrap-sb-admin-2 UI to Yii2 application

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, yii2

I found this Bootstrap UI from http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/ and I would like that my Yii2 application would look like it.

**How do I integrate that sb-admin-2 UI to my Yii2 application?** I already have a UI and I have tinkered the html and css of my app but I still find it dry and boring. That's why I want to use the **sb-admin-2 UI** from **Start Bootstrap** but I have no idea how to start.

I have read the instructions at their [GitHub page](https://github.com/IronSummitMedia/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2) but I still have a hard time understanding it.

Your help would be of great help. Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

I think that perhaps you are mis-understanding what a bootstrap theme is. It is simply a collection of css rules that you can apply to your content to make them look cool. You have to generate the content yourself. A bootstrap theme is not a module, or widget, or anything else like that.

To use it you just need to make sure to include the stylesheet, then apply the classes you want to the elements you have in your admin views. Have a look at the [demo](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-sb-admin-2/pages/index.html); it shows you all the different styles you can apply from the theme.

Yii have a [guide to including css and js assets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Yii2 SB Admin 2](https://github.com/NullRefExcep/yii2-sb-admin-2)

Installation

```
composer require nullref/yii2-sb-admin-2 "*"
```

Comment: Link only answers are not welcomed on SO. Please include essential part in answer.

Answer (score 0):

For integration new Theme in Yii2 you must do:

- create asset bundles for each functionality (forms, tables, wizards)
- create extended widgets for theme
- extend ActiveFileds - very complicated!!!
- create layouts

All this pieces, theme (css, js, imiges ) include in new module like Theme[Name]

Also very nice, if implement theme in Gii templates.